# Position a Div in Front of Another

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am trying to do something really simple here, I want a div with no border but a solid background color to be OVER a div with a border. This means I want the border around the second div to disappear behind the top div when they intersect. This is how the divs look as currently constructed:

[image]

Note here that I want DSP Name Settings to appear OVER the top border line. I have been using z-index but it changes essentially nothing. Here is my code as of right now. With the following CSS styles, that according to all Documentation, SHOULD be putting the title on top of the border as I would like, but isn't.

```
<div>
                <div class="set-preferences-name-data-title">
                    <h5 class="set-preferences-name-data-title-text">DSP Name Settings</h5>
                </div>
                <div>
                <div class="set-preferences-name-data">
                    <Form>
                        <Form.Group controlId="name" onChange={(event) => handleInput(event)}>
                            <Form.Control 
                                type='name'
                                placeholder={"name"}
                                style={{
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    border: '1px black',
                                    color: 'black',
                                }}
                            />  
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group controlId="shortcode" onChange={(event) => handleInput(event)}>
                            <Form.Control 
                                type='shortcode'
                                placeholder={"shortcode"}
                                style={{
                                    textAlign: 'center',
                                    border: '1px black',
                                    color: 'black',
                                }}
                            />  
                        </Form.Group>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title={"TimeZone"}>
                                <Dropdown.Item><Button className="set-preferences-dropdown-button" variant="info" onClick={() => handleSetTimeZone('EST') } size='lg'>Eastern Standard Time</Button></Dropdown.Item>
                                <Dropdown.Item><Button className="set-preferences-dropdown-button" variant="info" onClick={() => handleSetTimeZone('CT') } size='lg'>Central Time</Button></Dropdown.Item>     
                                <Dropdown.Item><Button className="set-preferences-dropdown-button" variant="info" onClick={() => handleSetTimeZone('MT') } size='lg'>Mountain Time</Button></Dropdown.Item>                                
                                <Dropdown.Item><Button className="set-preferences-dropdown-button" variant="info" onClick={() => handleSetTimeZone('PST') } size='lg'>Pacific Standard Time</Button></Dropdown.Item>                            
                            </DropdownButton>
                        </Form.Group>                        
                    </Form>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```css
.set-preferences-name-data {
  margin-left: 3%;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  padding-top: 30px !important;
  padding: 6px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: '#E2E8F1' !important;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -100 !important;
}

.set-preferences-name-data-title {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  background-color: 'white' !important;
  color: 'white';
  border: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: '#E2E8F1' !important;
  z-index: 20 !important;
}

.set-preferences-name-data-title {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: 'white' !important;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-right: 3px;
  z-index: 4 !important;
  left: 36.8%;
  top: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="set-preferences-name-data-title">
    <h5 class="set-preferences-name-data-title-text">DSP Name Settings</h5>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="set-preferences-name-data">
      <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="name" onChange={(event)=> handleInput(event)}> // I've commented out the first text input because it is irrelevant to the issue
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="shortcode" onChange={(event)=> handleInput(event)}> // I've commented out the second text input because it is irrelevant to the issue
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group>
          <DropdownButton id="dropdown-basic-button" title={dsp.timeZone}>
            // I removed the DropDown items since they're irrelevant to this issue
          </DropdownButton>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code that's in question is only rendered if a specified condition is met, so I will also post the main return of the React Component so to make everything a little more clear...

```
return(
        <div>
            <h1 className="set-preferences-title">Set ScoreCard Preferences</h1>
            <div>{renderNameSettings()}</div>
            <div className="PrefHeaderBox">
                <h2 className="set-preferences-header">
                    Here, you will be able to select at what point values for specific
                    ScoreCard values will be deemed 'fantastic', 'good' and 'fair'. Any time a value is 
                    higher than a 'fair' descending value or lower than a 'fair' ascending one, this 
                    value will be deemed 'subpar.' This will be reflected by what color the text pops up 
                    in for both you and your drivers
                </h2>
            </div>
       // The rest has been cut off since there is no relation to the rest of the component and the issue
```

Comment: it looks like your html is from a react render? I think you should include the actual output content so the css gets applied accordingly... like 'Set ScoreCard Preferences' isn't there

Comment: Remove the quotes around color names and hexcodes, that fixes the color problem

Comment: @Liquidchrome Gotcha, made the Edits. And Thank you for the help with the colors, that worked! I'm too used to 
React Native I guess

Comment: you can set background-color for div to hide second div border

Comment: I do, the top one with the higher z-index has a background color of white

Comment: @isherwood it's all inside of a ReactJs app, it needs to be `className` otherwise it doesn't properly compile

Comment: Ah yes my fault, give me a moment @isherwood

Comment: Ah, that was a typo, the second selector is `.set-preferences-name-data-title-text`

Comment: And now you've taken everything out of snippet demo mode. :/

Comment: The short answer, because I'm out of time to chase this, is that you should have both boxes inside a parent wrapper with position relative, then set position absolute on the box that overlays.

Comment: I will try. I appreciate the help @isherwood

Comment: @NickALanese We prefer questions about a single topic, that way, the answer to each question is easily available for others to search for. A little inconvenience for you to make your questions more useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a background-color on the top div:

```
.set-preferences-name-data-title {
  background-color: white;
}
```